Does NT Service\MSSQLSERVER represent the SQL engine irrespective of the actual service account?
My SQL server engine runs under mycompany\svc_sql_engine
However this account doesn't have any permissions on the SQL data and log drive folders/files.
The following account has the permissions:
NT Service\MSSQLSERVER
Does this mean that SQL engine uses this account behind the scenes to access the files?

Not that I've ever seen. How are you checking that the svc_sql_engine account does or does not have any access to the data and log files?

I right click on a few of the data and log folder and files, and under security I can see who all have access on the folder/file

It might be getting the permissions by virtue of being a member of a group.  In that case, you won't see svc_sql_engine in that list. Try the Effective Permissions tab -- that will show the permissions that the account gets by combining its own direct rights and any applicable group rights.

There are no groups as such in the list

Does the Effective Permissions tab show that svc_sql_engine has any rights to the data and log files?

My experience is that the permissions are the combined of those assigned to the virtual service account and those assigned to the startup account for the service.

@DougDeden - I checked via effective permissions. There is no permissions for that svc account.

Then I'm not sure what to try next. I've seen enough cases of "Access Denied" errors when starting up SQL that I'm 98% sure the service account needs access to the data and log files. Maybe include some screenshots confirming that your instance is running under that service account, and that the data and log files are in the place you are looking, and the results of the Effective Permissions tab/wizard. Some of that might click something in someone's brain.

@DougDeden - when changing service accounts, once you do the change in the SQL config manager, do you then manually then update the permission on data and log folders?

Yes. Or, sometimes, against my better judgement, we put the new service account in the local admins group, and that covers it.

I may have found something. Does your permissions info include an "account" named MSSQL$? The SQL installation process creates a per-service SID, and apparently even when you change the service account, the service is still tied to that SID, and that is what gives it access to the data and/or log directories.

Yes it's called NT Service\MSSQLSERVER (for default instance) as mentioned in the question. But this permission is on the file level. Do I wonder what gives it the folder permissions to be able to create these files for example when a new db.is created.
